# VS 2010 Power Tools - Align Assignments not working in VB.NET

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-power-tools

I'm using the Visual Studio 2010 Productivity Power Tools and I can't get the Align Assignments feature to work in VB.NET:

> [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef)
>
> **Align Assignments**
>
> This extension is useful for making
>   your code a little more readable by
>   aligning the assignments when you type
>   Ctrl+Alt+]
>
> Please note: This may conflict with
>   your formatting settings. E.g. in C#
>   you will need to disable:
>   Tools->Options->Text
>   Editor->C#->Formatting->Spacing->"Ignore
>   spaces in declaration statements"

When I put lots of spaces in a line of code and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> it reverts the line back to normal formatting. This indicates there's a conflict with my formatting settings. The problem is with VB.NET and I dont know how to "Ignore spaces in declaration statements"?

Comment: Disable "Pretty listing".  Kinda painful, I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

If this is not working for you, it could because your C# settings are stopping it. To , you must uncheck: Tools menu –> Options –> Text Editor –> C# –> Formatting –> Spacing –> Ignore spaces in declaration statements

Comment: I appreciate your answer but its doesn't work and unfortunately its Vb.Net... (I'd kill to use C# at work) I admire your thinking but its a bit too far outside the box.. as C# settings have no effect on VB * in this context anyway